# How to install SUMO on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu

I want to install [SUMO](http://sumo-sim.org/) on Ubuntu 10.10: I followed sumo installation guidelines step by step:

I installed packages necessary to build SUMO, I created a symbolic link `libgdal.so .`

I decompressed the tarball  and I moved the decompressed directory to `/usr/local/src`

Then I entered the source directory and I called configure:

```
$ ./configure --with-fox-includes=/usr/include/fox-1.6 \
--with-gdal-includes=/usr/include/gdal --with-proj-libraries=/usr \
--with-gdal-libraries=/usr --with-proj-gdal
```

In the configuration step I had this

```
error: configure :error:gdal-lib not found in “/usr”
```

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -l /usr/include/ |grep gdal`, `ls -l` on wherever that `libgdal.so` link is.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2013-09-10  11:45 gdal

Comment: hi this is what i get

Comment: hi
libgdal.so  is found under /usr/lib

Comment: What is "sumo"?

Comment: SUMO is  an open source for Simulation of Urban MObility

Answer (score 2):

#### Install gdal-lib

That error is telling you that you need to install gdal-lib. You can download it from here, as pre-packaged binaries.

- http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadingGdalBinaries

You could also use your package manager `apt-get` to try installing the package that includes this library + it's header files.

```
$ apt-get install libgdal-dev
```

You'll need to re-run the configure script before proceeding.

#### Change to configure command

Try changing your configure line to this instead:

```
$ ./configure --with-fox-includes=/usr/include/fox-1.6 \
--with-gdal-includes=/usr/include/gdal --with-proj-libraries=/usr \
--with-gdal-libraries=/usr/lib --with-proj-gdal
```

Comment: My guess is, `libgdal-dev` would be more pertinent here.

Comment: @JosephR. - thank you I'm at work and did not recall the naming convention for Ubuntu's library packages.

Comment: hi 
i already installed libgdal-dev

Comment: @MYnoussa slm's point (I think) is that you should pass `/usr/lib` to `./configure` instead of `/usr`.

Comment: @terdon - thanks that was my point 8-)

Comment: I did this but i had the same error :

Comment: gdal-lib not found in /usr/lib